# Pass a context to a "require"d javascript module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm just having a play around with some testing and I've been following this example to write a module: http://www.richardrodger.com/2013/09/27/how-to-make-simple-node-js-modules-work-in-the-browser/#.Vt74CvmLT0M

I'm using a change I saw somewhere to check for "window" and use it else use "this". I've simplified an example below:

```
(function() {
     'use strict';
     var root = this;
     var previous_myModule = root.myModule;

     var myModule = function() { };

     myModule.noConflict = function() {
         root.myModule = previous_myModule;
         return myModule;
     };

     if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
         if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
             exports = module.exports = myModule;
         }
         exports.myModule = myModule;
     } else {
         root.myModule = myModule;
     }
}).call(typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : this);
```

The example I copied from tries to emulate jquery's noConflict to remove the module from the namespace if required.

I am testing with Mocha and using Istanbul for code coverage. I noticed that the "noConflict" function has no line coverage so I thought I'd just have a look and see if I could test it but it seems that I cannot pass in any value that could be the "window" value. It is always undefined and "this" is used instead.

I have tried setting "var window..." and "global.window" in the test module but this doesn't work.

Is there any way I can pass a context into this module so that I could test if the noConflict function does actually revert the value that it sets on the "window"?

EDIT:
The value of window, if set, is passed into the function as the "this" value because of function.prototype.call. My problem is that I cannot make window anything but unassigned and I'd like to emulate the behaviour of the browser within my test environment.

```
console.log(window); // window is undefined here, unless inside a browser
(function() {....
```

Comment: I've actually managed to get this to work using global but I'm not sure how and it definitely didn't work earlier. I'll investigate and follow this up if I work out more.